# How to choose secp256k1 private key?

Tags: elliptic-curves, secp256k1

The private key is any random 256 bit (but smaller than prime p) number or must be prime or other condition?
For selected $x$ can be found $y$ - decompressing key:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import binascii
import math
p = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFC2F
def decompress_pubkey(pk):
    x = int.from_bytes(pk[1:33], byteorder='big')
    y_sq = (pow(x, 3, p) + 7) % p
    y = pow(y_sq, (p + 1) // 4, p)
    if y % 2 != pk[0] % 2:
        y = p - y
    y = y.to_bytes(32, byteorder='big')
    return b'\x04' + pk[1:33] + y

print(binascii.hexlify(decompress_pubkey(binascii.unhexlify('0229b3e0919adc41a316aad4f41444d9bf3a9b639550f2aa735676ffff25ba3898'))).decode())
print(binascii.hexlify(decompress_pubkey(binascii.unhexlify('02f15446771c5c585dd25d8d62df5195b77799aa8eac2f2196c54b73ca05f72f27'))).decode())
print(binascii.hexlify(decompress_pubkey(binascii.unhexlify('0279be667ef9dcbbac55a06295ce870b07029bfcdb2dce28d959f2815b16f81798'))).decode())
```

Only last x,y pair fulfill (x**3+7-y**2) % p is zero. Two previous pairs are wrong?

Comment: Reading the doc helps, here [section 3.2.1 in Sec1v2](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#page=29). It allows to answer the first sentence by: other condition, but the first guess was close.

Comment: Note for the programming part see [Deriving an ECDSA uncompressed public key from a compressed one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43654055/1820553)

Comment: @fgrieu I've read this question incorrectly. This is a completely a python coding problem. The OP wants to find the $y$ coordinate of the public key and the coding part is not correct. I've given a link that handles this correctly,

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing the concepts; the private key vs the public key. Your private key $k$ is an integer which is selected uniform randomly between $1$ to order of the base point $G$, $k \in[1,n-1]$.

- Basepoint $G$ in compressed for

  ```
    0279BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798
  ```
- **The order** $n$ of $G$, i.e. $[n]G = \mathcal{O}$, where $\mathcal{O}$ is point at infinity, or the identity element in additive elliptic curve group.

  `FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFE BAAEDCE6 AF48A03B BFD25E8C`

Your (or any) public key is $[k]G$, which is scalar multiplication and defined as.

$$[k]G = \overbrace{G+\cdots+G}^{{k\hbox{ - }times}}$$

With add [double-and-add](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Double-and-add) it can be calculated very efficiently in $\mathcal{O}(\log(n))$-time.

Your failures are due to your python coding ( that is off-topic here) where you want to recover the $y$ value from a compressed public key, not the private key. [Rasmus Faber's has an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43654055/1820553) in StackOverflow. That is the way you need to find it with Python.

**Note**: All parameters of the curve can be found on Certicom's [SEC 2: Recommended Elliptic Curve Domain Parameters](http://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf)

Comment: Not for all x is solution, but how to choose correct x? because private key must have correct x.

Comment: No, as written, the private key is an integer. The public key is a point. What you want is given a compressed public key, you want to find the $y$. In this case, with correct implementation, as linked, you can find it. Note that with the compressed you will reach $y$ and $-y$. The encoding tells to choose the correct one.