# How fast compute high degree power in finite field?

Tags: finite-field

We need find y for some x on elliptical curve in cases:

- decompressing public key
- restoring public key from signature for given message hash, r and s.

This algorithm uses power twice: first it is y1 = $x^3$ modulo p, and next is very high degree y = $y1^{(p + 1) / 4}$ modulo p.
I know way to compute it on logarithmic time, similar to adding-doubling method, where instead adding is multiplying , instead doubling is compute square.
I wonder, if is faster method for special exponent, here exponent is not arbitrary but (p + 1) / 4.
I'm afraid that restoring public key from signature takes much more time than verify signature.

Comment: Not a good question, again. My first advice, start upvote and accept the answers so that the community can see that the answer is satisfied with the OP. In the current state, it seems that you are not satisfied at all. I guess that you are talking about the curve equation $y^2 = x^3  + 7$ over the prime field, but where it is on the question? You don't restore the public key from the signature, you know the public key explicitly. Still, it is finding the $y$ coordinate if the public key is given in the compressed form.

Comment: And you saw it from the previous [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/86303/18298). The formula special to some curves. If you afraid of the timing, then ask the person to not store the public key in the compressed from or build a database so that you can use the information again and again.

Comment: I check. It is fast. Because multiplication of finite field is more more faster than multiplication ellipse point by number. Computing square root by computing very high degree power is faster than multiplication of ellipse point. Thanks, this speed is enough for me.